# 'Where is the number 1'? or 'Where is the digit 1'? or simply 'where is 1'?

Tags: pedagogy

While practicing numbers with children, what's the natural way to ask them about identifying numbers among mixed numbers?

**'Where is the number 1'?**

Vs.

**'Where is the digit 1'?**

Vs.

**simply 'where is 1'?**

Or other ways?

Comment: "Where is the number 1?" or "Where is the 1?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with young children, it's best not to complicate matters. Generally you start children off with pictures, and ask questions like "Where is the rabbit?" or "Where is the apple?".

In the same way, when you are asking children to identify the symbols that represent the digits, you would ask the question in the same way... "Where is the one?".